# Filter only the text in the_content

Tags: posts, the-content, text

I tried to filter only the text in `get_the_content` for my home page,
but its including my shortcode also, because in that page first row google map 2nd row text box i am using visual composer page builder.

**My code**

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters('the_content', substr(get_the_content(), 0, 60) );
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content
```

**My result**

> [vc_row][vc_column][vc_gmaps
>   link=”#E-8_JTNDaWZyYW1lJTIwc3Jj

screenshot

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly with the filter? At the moment your code is only grabbing the first 60 characters of the post, which is resulting in what looks like a broken shortcode. You'd probably be better off just replacing all of your code with `the_content()`

Comment: I just want to skip the sortcodes from the content. i want to display the 2nd row text.

Comment: Ah got it. Just posted an answer for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment clarifying what you want to achieve, it appears you want to display the first 60 characters of your post *not including any shortcodes*.

To do this you can use the `strip_shortcodes()` function. Rewritten with that, your code will look like this:

```
$content = strip_shortcodes(get_the_content());
$content = apply_filters('the_content', substr($content, 0, 60) );
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
```

All we're doing here is running the content (from `get_the_content()`) through `strip_shortcodes()` before applying Wordpress filters on the first 60 characters.

Depending on what you want to achieve and whether you're relying on any other plugins modifying this content for you, you actually might be fine to skip the `apply_filters()` call as well - in which case all you'd need to do is set `$content` to the `substr()` you want to have.

Comment: not working anyway thanks, for now i will use get_the_excerpt().

Comment: That's probably a better option if you're happy with it :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
do_shortcode(get_the_content($id));
```

instead

Comment: Please file an [edit]] and explain *why*. Please first read [answer] to get tips on how to write a good answer